# Cannot update row connecting to database via dataset

Tags: c#, dataset, row

I'm trying to update a row in a table.
If row.FirstMessageId == null then I ask the Messages table for the first message for that specific chat.
I then put the Message.id into row.FirstMessageId

But... nothing happens.  Database is not updated.

What am I missing?
Thank you. :)

```
using (ChatsTableAdapter chatsTableAdapter = new ChatsTableAdapter())
using (ArchiveDataSet.ChatsDataTable chats = chatsTableAdapter.GetData())
    foreach (ArchiveDataSet.ChatsRow chat in chats)
    {
        if (chat.IsFirstMessageIdNull())
            using (ArchiveDataSet.MessagesDataTable messages =
                new MessagesTableAdapter().GetFirstMessage
                (chat.ChatId))

        if (messages.Rows.Count is 1)
        {
            ArchiveDataSet.MessagesRow message = (ArchiveDataSet.MessagesRow)(messages.Rows[0]);
            chat.FirstMessageId = message.MessageId;
            chat.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you debug? is there any data in `chats` variable?

Comment: did you put some breakpoints to check?

Comment: are you sure you are connected to db successfully?

Comment: Yes, I have the data from the DB.
I added a new column to my table, and want to fill it up as I go and use.

Comment: so when you put the breakpoint on `foreach`  you find data, but when you try to update you can not? is it?

Comment: What is the details of this `chat.AcceptChanges();` method

Comment: Can you provide more detailed class codes, if possible?

Comment: by editing the post and adding them, please

Comment: The classes are the ones generated by Visual Studio when creating the dataset from a SQL database.
Data goes into `chat.FirstMessage`, but it does not make it into the sql table.

The AcceptChanges in inherited by the `ChatsRow` from
`System.Data.DataRow.AcceptChanges()`

Comment: A command has four methods 1) Select 2) Update 3) Insert 4) Delete.  For the AccecptChanges to work you need all four methods.  A commandbuilder take a select method and automatically creates the other three.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: @jdweng , I'm not doing the coding (the part that connects to the sql database) myself. I used Visual Studio create dataset tool. Either way... did some more experimenting, and it works. Publishing the solution now. Thank you both.

Comment: I'm glad you found something that works but have you considered using an ORM to handle the database interactions for you? LINQtoSQL is still part of .NET, Entity Frameworks is an ugly but versatile system, Linq2DB is fairly easy to use... there are a lot of alternatives that will make life simpler for you.

Comment: @Corey, please don't make my life even more complicated. My field of work is political science/philosophy. This software is for a research, I need to collect information (a lot - I have 4 million rows in one of my tables and the thing is just starting) so I can later run some statistical analysis on it. All I want is for it to work. :p

Comment: @MarioLOBO Trust me, a good ORM will make things MUCH more simple for you. That's what they're designed to do. Take a day, learn how to use Linq2DB or something else, you won't regret it. (I contribute to Linq2DB occasionally, FYI.)

Comment: @Corey, Ok.... you won. :)
After a pause on the project (too long for my taste, I'm back into it).
I'm having troubles installing Linq2SQL something with connection string.

Is there a way for me to contact you directly and, pleeeeeeeeease, ask for some guidance?

Comment: @Corey, done. My bad :)
But I'll be back... I'm sure of it

Comment: Linq2DB has some NuGet packages that help generate the row objects and DataContext class. Install the one that's right for your database engine - `LinqToDB.SqlServer`, `LinqToDB.MySql` or whatever. Copy the T4 template, fill in the connection string, let it generate the template for you. Check it out on GitHub: https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db

Answer (score 1):

Solution found.
I update the data via `chatsTableAdapter.Update(row)`.

(never mind the `if (messages.Rows.Count is 1)`, the original database is not 'clean' which means I, for now, better ignore some things)

```
using (ChatsTableAdapter chatsTableAdapter = new ChatsTableAdapter())
using (ArchiveDataSet.ChatsDataTable chats = chatsTableAdapter.GetData())
    foreach (ArchiveDataSet.ChatsRow chat in chats)
    {
        if (chat.IsFirstMessageIdNull())
            using (ArchiveDataSet.MessagesDataTable messages =
                new MessagesTableAdapter().GetFirstMessage(chat.ChatId))
                if (messages.Rows.Count is 1)
                {
                    ArchiveDataSet.MessagesRow message = (ArchiveDataSet.MessagesRow)(messages.Rows[0]);
                    chat.FirstMessageId = message.MessageId;
                    chatsTableAdapter.Update(chat);
                }
    }
```

Comment: Update will only change values that already in the database and will not add new values (also does not do delete).

Comment: It is actually putting the `FirstMessageId` into the proper column.

Comment: I said above,  There are four types of commands 1) Select 2) Update 3) Insert 4) Delete.  Your code is only doing Select and Update, not Insert and Delete.  You need a Command Builder to do all four.

Comment: My original question was about update, and why it was not updating.

Comment: You original code had "chat.AcceptChanges();" and accept changes required all 4 methods.